# Pandas groupby multiple columns, but treat separately (don't want unique combinations)

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the following dataframe

| c1 | c2 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| p | x | 1 |
| n | x | 2 |
| n | y | 1 |
| p | y | 2 |
| p | y | 1 |
| n | x | 2 |

etc. I then want this in the following format:

| p | n | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 5 | 5 | 4 |

i.e., i want to sum column 3 for each group in columns 1 & 2, but I don't want the unique combinations of columns 1 & 2, which would be achieved by grouping by those columns and summing on the third. Any way to do this using groupby?

Comment: you could do two separate groupby calls (one on c1 and one on c2) and then merge the results

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read how to ask good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure your question covers these 3 elements: 1. Problem Statement 2. Your Code (it should be [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 3. Error Message (preferably full Traceback to help others review and provide feedback). Sometimes the same question may have already been asked. Make sure your question is not a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Answer (score 0):

As Karan said, just call `groupby` on each of your label columns separately, then concatenate (and transpose) the results:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['p', 'x', 1],
                   ['n', 'x', 2], 
                   ['n', 'y', 1],
                   ['p', 'y', 2],
                   ['p', 'y', 1],
                   ['n', 'x', 2]])
df.columns = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']

sums1 = df.groupby('c1').sum()
sums2 = df.groupby('c2').sum()

sums = pd.concat([sums1, sums2]).T
sums
```

```py
    n   p   x   y
c3  5   4   5   4
```